# Jquery datepicker setDate subtracts one day of the given date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use the datepickers method setDate to set the date.

Somehow setDate sets the date to the given date minus one day. I am using a date object. Does anyone know why this happens?

Two pieces of my code

```
to1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
//do stuff   
$(this).datepicker( "setDate", "to1" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set to change date when ‘r’ is false when you should have set the condition to change when ‘r’ is true.

- True - when clicked on OK
- False - when clicked on cancel

Comment: this isn't the problem. My problem is that setDate changes the date to "to1" minus one day. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Remove the quotes surrounding to1: `$(this).datepicker( "setDate", to1 );`

Comment: ai, doesn't work.. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Decided to go for another approach. Thanks @hungersoft